# How to interpolate pixel coordinates instead of pixel value? Need it for to generate a correction remap for a camera

Tags: c++, opencv

Traditionally, when processing an image, interpolation is done to the pixel value. My case is I need to generate a remap (on PC) to be put in an embedded system with a camera for further processing, such that any processing algorithms could directly refer to the remap instead of having to process every frame beforehand. Like so (ofc not written like this in application, just a demo):

```cpp
struct Point { //A pixel on the image
    int x, y
} original, corrected;

//I want every entry in this remap to have a valid value
float remap[width][height][2] = ...; //Contains the new pixel coordinates of each pixel
```

```cpp
//I want the processes in the embedded system to be able to do this with every pixel
//But now it is not possible as not every pixel has a corresponding mapX and mapY
corrected.x = remap[original.x][original.y][0]; //mapX
corrected.y = remap[original.x][original.y][1]; //mapY
```

One of processes to generate the remap is radial distortion correction using OpenCV. As OpenCV uses an inverse map `dst(x, y) = src(mapX(x, y), mapY(x, y))`, I inversed it again such that `dst(mapX(x, y), mapY(x, y)) = src(x, y)`. But then some `x, y` does not have a corresponding `mapX, mapY` after the correction.

I need every `x, y` to have a corresponding `mapX, mapY` for the processes on the embedded system to work properly. How can I interpolate the pixel coordinates instead of the pixel value?

So far I tried simply averaging out `mapX, mapY` values in the surrounding area, but did not work well.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.width * parameters.height; ++i) {
    if (!status[i]) { //If no corresponding mapX, mapY
        double avgX = 0, avgY = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int y = -5; y < 5; ++y) { //A square surrounding the pixel being interpolated
            for (int x = -5; x < 5; ++x) {
                int num = std::min(std::max(0, i + y * parameters.width + x), parameters.width * parameters.height);
                if (status[num]) { //If this pixel has a corresponding mapX, mapY
                    avgX += mapX[num];
                    avgY += mapY[num];
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        //If at least 1 pixel in the surrounding area has a corresponding mapX, mapY
        if (avgX != 0 || avgY != 0) {
            avgX /= count;
            avgY /= count;
            mapX[i] = avgX;
            mapY[i] = avgY;
            status[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to have a look at [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)…

Comment: arent the pixel positions encoded as map values (pixel values of mapX and mapY are the positions)?!? Can you give a short (reduced) example of what you want to do? In things like keypoint position subpixel estimation, afair they use some curve local optima interpolated from the whole neighborhood to find the subpixel coordinates.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thus far all of the explanations I found is using 4 known pixels that form a rectangle to interpolate some pixel in between, but I don't know how I can get 4 known surrounding pixels, as this is not something as simple as a resize.

Comment: @Micka I didn't completely understand your question, but I tried to do some edits to my questions to make it clearer. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: so the problem is, that the maps are not dense? Have a look at depth map literature (kinect, stereo vision, etc.), where you'll find some approaches for filling such holes.

Answer (score 0):

warning probably

> ```
>  int num = std::min(std::max(0, i + y * parameters.width + x), parameters.width * parameters.height);
> ```

must be

```
int num = std::min(std::max(0, i + y * parameters.width + x), parameters.width * parameters.height - 1);
```

because of `for (int i = 0; i < parameters.width * parameters.height; ++i)` (I mean `i < parameters.width * parameters.height` rather than `i <= parameters.width * parameters.height`)

---

*avgX* and *avgY* are modified only if `(status[num])` is true, are some entries of *status* containing *true* before to do the overall *for* ?

Comment: The `status` array is to record whether that pixel has a corresponding `mapX, mapY`, it may be the case that even the surrounding pixels don't have a mapping too, so that's why I put that check there. This is a new acc so I can't post pics to visualise.

Comment: @Hogcryat ok but if _status_ contains 0 for all the entries before to reach the `for (int i = 0; i < parameters.width * parameters.height; ++i)` that loop does absolutely nothing because _avgX/avgY_ will always value 0 so `(avgX != 0 || avgY != 0)` is never true and _mapX/mapY_ is never modified

Comment: True. So it was by no means a solution, I was just testing it out to see if it is worth expanding on it, but no, it added a lot of noise to the image so I just ditched it and asked for solutions here. As I don't know much about interpolation. I've looked into bilinear interpolation, but the explanations I found all used 4 known pixels forming a rectangle, the problem is I am not doing a simple resize and I have no idea how to get those 4 pixels.